# Use CKEditor on textarea in custom module's controller response

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I am trying to figure out how to use Drupal 8's CKEditor on `<textarea></textarea>` tags that are part of a controllers markup and not generated from a Drupal form.

Has anyone done this or can Drupal 8's integrated CKEditor only be used with Drupal Forms?

When I try to use ckeditor with the standard way of `CKEDITOR.replace('element');` I get the error that `config.js` and `styles.js` are missing.  Which should be the case because Drupal has consciously excluded them from their integrated CKEditor. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2604052

After digging around I found the javascript call `Drupal.editors.ckeditor.attach(element, format)` but I can't figure out what to pass in for the `format` parameter.  Looking at other javascript code it appears they they use the `drupalSettings` global variable in javascript to pass it in but it's not there.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

My code is below.

**my_module.routing.yml**

```
my_module.myroute:
  path: '/my-route'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Test Module'
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\HomeController::view'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

**my_module.libraries.yml**

```
scripts:
  js:
    my_script.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - ckeditor/drupal.ckeditor
```

**my_script.js**

```
window.onload = function () {
    let element = jQuery("#testelement");
    let format = "filtered_html";
    Drupal.editors.ckeditor.attach(element, format);
};
```

**HomeController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

class HomeController extends ControllerBase
{

    function view()
    {
        return [
            "#attached" => [
                "library" => ["my_module/scripts"]
            ],
            "#markup" => Markup::create("
                <textarea name='testelement' id='testelement'></textarea>            
            ")
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: But why? Is this a form to be submitted? Why not just create a form through FormBase?

Comment: Because i'm trying to add ckeditor to multiple forms that were not created using `FormBase` so I don't have to rewrite them all.

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine you just return the same element you'd build into a form, and use a format that's configured to use a WYSIWYG:

```
return [
  '#attached' => ...,
  '#type' => 'text_format',
  '#title' => 'Foo',
  '#format' => 'full_html', 
];
```

See the [`TextFormat`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21filter%21src%21Element%21TextFormat.php/class/TextFormat/8.2.x) class for more options.

Comment: I would agree with @clive, form elements don't have to be used in a form, you can use them in any page output. However, you may need to attach the appropriate library to the page (if CKEditor doesn't render).

Comment: You didn't read my question correctly or I didn't explain it clear enough.  I am not using `Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase` to create the form.  The forms were created in plain html and i'm trying to re-add ckeditor to the form without recreating it using FormBase.

Comment: I did try and return what you have from my controller response and that didn't really change anything.  The page was empty, no form element was created.

Answer (score 0):

Missed the format

```
return [

  '#type' => 'text_format',
   '#title' => t('Text'),
   '#required' => TRUE,
   '#format' => 'full_html',
   "#attached" => [
   "library" => ["my_module/scripts"]
            ]
  ];
```

Go to /admin/config/content/formats and check the CKeditor is enabled for FULL HTML. Also, could be a role issue, by default Full HTML is for admins only.

Comment: It's not a permissions / role issue as I can get CKEditor to load fine when using `Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase`.  I am trying to add ckeditor to forms that were not created using FormBase without having to rewrite the entire thing.